# Who first chose the names Alice and Bob for players A and B?

Tags: pr.probability, set-theory, ho.history-overview, computer-science, game-theory

Who first chose the names Alice and Bob for the players (or observers) A and B?

Comment: The [recent question of mine](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/304973/forcing-and-family-contentions-who-wins-the-disputes) might be of your interest if you would like to know more about the personal life of this famous game-theoretic couple! ;-P

Comment: https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/6536

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it belongs on HSM and seems to have an answer there

Comment: @YemonChoi The question is very much unanswered there.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Thank you, I should have said "there is a plausible answer left in the comments, via Wikipedia"

Comment: @YemonChoi The question there is about physics and  Alexandre Eremenko called into question whether it originated in CS.

Comment: Can't resist: Alice chose first.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Quoted from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alice_and_Bob):

> *The Alice and Bob characters were invented by Ron Rivest, Adi Shamir, and Leonard Adleman in their 1978 paper "A method for obtaining digital signatures and public-key cryptosystems".*

*Rivest, R. L.; Shamir, A.; Adleman, L.*, [**A method for obtaining digital signatures and public-key cryptosystems**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/359340.359342), Commun. ACM 21, 120-126 (1978). [ZBL0368.94005](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0368.94005).

Comment: It might have been inspired by the 1969 film [Bob & Carol & Ted & Alice]([Bob & Carol & Ted & Alice), which led to these names being utilized in [earlier work](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-94-010-2506-5_27).

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker (+1) Interesting observation, Michael! The date proximity between paper and film supports your claim! :-)

Comment: Thank you Morteza Azad for the convincing answer and the reference to your recent related question.

Comment: And also thank you Michael Greinecker for the so interesting observation !

Comment: So I guess it's not in honor of Alice Silverberg and Bob Silverman.

Comment: @GerryMyerson (+1) Hahaha...cool! ;-P Let me use the opportunity to point out to [Alice's Adventures in Numberland](https://sites.google.com/site/numberlandadventures/), the blog that I like and read occadionally. No need to say that I am personally a great fan of puns and all manners of word games. It seems Alice Silverberg also has such a good sense of humor.

Answer (score 16):

Allow me to mention that since the players in effect adopt the roles of the quantifiers $\forall$ and $\exists$, as Bob has a winning strategy just in case for every move for Alice, there is a reply by Bob, and so on, some logicians have preferred to use alternative names that would better highlight this connection.

When I was a graduate student attending lectures of Adrian Mathias in Berkeley, he used the names [Abelard and Éloïse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Abelard#The_letters_of_Abelard_and_H%C3%A9lo%C3%AFse), after the famous couple and their love letters at court (made more interesting by the fact that Abelard was a logician). The advantage, you see, is that the names begin with A and E, aligning with $\forall$ and $\exists$.

Another example, of course, would be Adam and Eve, although Mathias preferred Abelard and Éloïse. In truth, however, I recall that Mathias  was not fully satisfied with either of these examples, and sought additional famous couples, whose names begin with A and E. Does anyone know any?

Let me collect here the examples of A/E names of famous pairs contributed in the comments and elsewhere.

- [Abelard and Éloïse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Abelard#The_letters_of_Abelard_and_H%C3%A9lo%C3%AFse), the famous lovers. Abelard was a logician
- [Adam and Eve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adam_and_Eve), from the creation myth
- Anna and Elsa, from the Disney film, Frozen
- [Arwen and Elessar](http://www.theonering.com/galleries/professional-artists/the-return-of-the-king/arwen-and-elessar-hildebrandt) (otherwise known as Aragorn), from the Tolkien saga. Connected with infinity and eternal life.
- Albert and Elizabeth, British royals
- [Ares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ares) and [Enyo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enyo), Greek gods of war

Please add more in the comments!

Comment: Meanwhile, for uses in cryptographic protocols, there is a larger cast of characters: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alice_and_Bob.

Comment: Not a couple in the romantic sense, but Anna and Elsa from the Disney film Frozen might help sell logic to a younger crowd.

Comment: (+1) Enjoyed reading your answer, Joel! And yes, I also have heard of the  Abelard and Éloïse couple (and loved it). By the way, I believe the $\forall$-$\exists$ view of the games and the corresponding interpretation of the Axiom of Determinacy as [an infinitary De Morgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_determinacy#Infinite_logic_and_the_axiom_of_determinacy) applied to formulas with alternating $\forall$ and $\exists$ quantifiers, is a terrific way of talking about games and determinacy specific to logicians.

Comment: As Joel says, cryptography has additional characters, such as "Eve" the "eavesdropper." A propos of which, people might enjoy the Alice and Bob XKCD cartoon: https://xkcd.com/177/

Comment: I would like to mention my all-time favorite couple, **Arwen & [Elessar](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Aragorn_II_Elessar)** (aka Aragorn). One particular aspect of this love story that (as a set theorist) I like the most is the role of infinity and choice! Arwen is an immortal elf who is [warned by his father](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_i3Ax4YJySg), Lord Elrond, about the consequences of marrying a mortal man who eventually will die after finitely-many years and will leave his lover in eternal grief! This inevitable fate makes her choose to give up her elfish immortality to be with him!

Comment: That's a nice example, except my impression is that Aragorn is known mainly by that name and less so by Elessar, which lessens the otherwise great appeal of the example.

Comment: Albert and Elizabeth

Comment: Also the quantifier symbols are reflections about x-,y- axes, upside down or right side left.

Comment: Would Ares and Enyo qualify ?

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN That's a great example! The gods-of-war aspect aligns with the competitive nature of games.

Comment: Thank you. I guess Greek mythology as well as others can provide more examples but indeed seeing games as wars makes sense.

Comment: Yes, I am thinking that perhaps both war and logician's games involve planning for strategic advantage at the essence.

Comment: Also, in Norse mythology Ask and Embla were the first humans. Due to the fact that in English the meaning of ask is related to questioning, I find it worth mentioning.

Comment: @M.G. Really? In any case, let me mention that it helps in the logic of games usage to have an opposite sex couple, since then the players can be conveniently distinguished by he/she pronouns (although I suppose nontraditional pronouns could work in other cases, but not yours).

Comment: Anna Kournikova & Enrique Iglesias. Too soon?

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins: No, I wasn't being serious :-)

Comment: About Eve... Alice, Bob *and* Eve are commonly used in cryptography. Eve being the Eavesdropper.

Comment: Go in a WW2 with Allied Forces and Evil Axis.

Comment: The use of Abélard and Éloïse is due to Wilfred Hodges. See page 6:
http://wilfridhodges.co.uk/semantics06.pdf
His undergraduate degree was in theology.

Comment: @RobertFurber Thanks for that reference (+1); it seems probable that Mathias had got it from Hodges. But I wonder if there is a better, much earlier reference? That article is 2009, and I heard Mathias using these names in 1992 or so.

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN Re Ask and Embla: that's pronounced "Ash", as in ash tree, and has nothing to do with asking questions.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins I've just checked -- Hodges uses it in his book *Building Models by Games*, at the bottom of page 23. This was published in 1985.

Comment: If the state space is large, I might use [Arges](http://mythology.wikia.com/wiki/Arges) and [Brontes](http://mythology.wikia.com/wiki/Brontes).  From a practical standpoint ("playgames" as opposed to "mathgames") we're looking at Ultraviolet vs. Infrared ("U&I") as a replacement for "black and white".  Since we have to blend colors for the Mbrane (partisan sudoku) heatmaps, RGB will likely be the default for the three player game.

Comment: Gro-Tsen replied on Twitter: “Ἀχιλλεύς and Ἕκτωρ, of course. (That's Achilles and Hector, but you have to write it in Greek for Ektôr to start with an E. Héloïse cheats in much the same way.)” https://twitter.com/gro_tsen/status/1018997839349846016